# Using LearningRateMultipliers in a recurrent neural network

Tags: neural-networks

I'm trying to use `LearningRateMultipliers` in a recurrent neural network, but I haven't found the right way yet.

An example of the code is as follows:

```
fixed = LinearLayer[2, "Weights" -> {{1., 0.5}, {0., 1.}}, "Biases" -> None]
core = NetGraph[<|"l1" -> TotalLayer[], "l2" -> LinearLayer[2, "Input" -> 2], "l3" -> fixed|>, {{NetPort["Input"], NetPort["State"]} -> "l1" -> "l2" -> "l3"}]
fold = NetFoldOperator[core, "Input" -> {"Varying", 2}]

net = NetTrain[fold, io, LearningRateMultipliers -> {_ -> 0.1, 3 -> 0}]
net[["Parameters"]]["Net"][["l3"]][["Weights"]]
(*The network training ends but the value of the l3 weights are changed*)

net = NetTrain[fold, io, LearningRateMultipliers -> {3 -> 0, _ -> 0.1}]
(*The command gives an error*)

net = NetTrain[fold, io, LearningRateMultipliers -> {_ -> 0.1, fold[["Parameters"]]["Net"][["l3"]] -> 0}]
(*The network training ends but the value of the l3 weights are changed*)

net = NetTrain[fold, io, LearningRateMultipliers -> {fold[["Parameters"]]["Net"][["l3"]] -> 0, _ -> 0.1}]
(*The command gives an error*)
```

What is the right way to change the learning rate in only one layer of a recurrent neural network?

Moreover, while looking for a way to solve the problem, I found a strange behaviour in a `NetGraph`. Please check the code.

```
fixed = LinearLayer[2, "Weights" -> {{1., 0.5}, {0., 1.}},"Biases" -> None]
core = NetInitialize@NetGraph[{LinearLayer[2, "Input" -> 2], fixed}, {NetPort["Input"] -> 1 -> 2}]
io = {{1, 2} -> {1, 2}};
net = NetTrain[core, io, LearningRateMultipliers -> {2 -> 0, _ -> 0.1}]
net[[2]][["Weights"]] (*Works*)
net = NetTrain[core, io, LearningRateMultipliers -> {_ -> 0.1, 2 -> 0}]
net[[2]][["Weights"]] (*Not works without warrning*)
```

The fact that the order of this list is important is reported nowhere.

Comment: From the documentation on `LearningRateMultipliers`: "For each trainable array, the rate used is given by the first matching rule, or 1 if no rule matches." That's why the order of the list is important.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `NetInformation` to see how you should refer to the layers inside of the network:

```
In[89]:= fold = NetInitialize[fold];
NetInformation[fold, "Arrays"]

Out[90]= <|{"Net", "l2", "Biases"} -> {0., 0.}, {"Net", "l2", "Weights"} -> {{0.517432, -0.660375},
  {-0.524418, 0.517747}}, {"Net", "l3", "Weights"} -> {{1., 0.5}, {0., 1.}}|>
```

So if you want to freeze the 3rd layer in `core`, use

```
LearningRateMultipliers -> {{"Net", "l3"} -> 0, _ -> 1}
```

or

```
LearningRateMultipliers -> {{"Net", "l3", "Weights"} -> 0, _ -> 1}
```